# How to perform better filtering in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this filtering applied in my admin. But there are around 200 and much more unique id which is getting displayed on the right.

How can I limit them?
Is there are a better way to do this?

```
@admin.register(Model)
class Model(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['my_unique_id']
```

Screenshot of the admin
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your related model?

Comment: You might want to use `search_fields=['my_unique_id']` instead of the `list_filter`.

Comment: That doesn;t give me the list of ids on the right hand side, I want something like pagination kinda thing in the my list of ids. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If 'my_unique_id' field is CharField then you should use search_fields = ['my_unique_id'].

If 'my_unique_id' field is ForeignKey then you can use RelatedFieldListFilter and customize template.

You can override template for dropdown

related_dropdown_filter.html

```
{% load i18n %}
<script type="text/javascript">var go_from_select = function(opt) { window.location = window.location.pathname + opt };</script>
<div class="dropDown-filter">
<h3>{% blocktrans with title as filter_title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<ul class="admin-filter-{{ title|cut:' ' }}">
{% if choices|slice:"1:" %}
    <li>
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 95%;margin-left: 2%;"
        onchange="go_from_select(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <option{% if choice.selected %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
         value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </li>
{% else %}

    {% for choice in choices %}
            <li{% if choice.selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</ul>
</div>
```

```
from django.contrib.admin.filters import RelatedFieldListFilter

class RelatedDropdownFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):
    template = 'related_dropdown_filter.html'


@admin.register(Model)
class Model(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [('my_unique_id', RelatedDropdownFilter)]
```

Comment: But I still want to see the list of ids on my right-hand side. I was thinking of maybe having something like a separate filtering form kind of thing

Comment: @Comrade49 I edited the answer. You can customise the template for dropdown filter.